# Selecting n points to have a given mean and covariance

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I have a set $N$ points in $d$-dimensional space, $\mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^d ~~ \forall i=\{1,2,...,N\}$. How to choose $n$ points from the set such that it maximises
$$
f = |\mathbf{S}|^{-n/2} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{tr}\left(\mathbf{S}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\right) - \frac{n}{2} (\boldsymbol{\mu} - \mathbf{\bar{x}})^T \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} (\boldsymbol{\mu} - \mathbf{\bar{x}})\right],
$$
for given $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ and $\boldsymbol{\mu}$, where $\mathbf{S} = \sum_j (\mathbf{x}_j - \mathbf{\bar{x}})  (\mathbf{x}_j - \mathbf{\bar{x}})^T$ and $\mathbf{\bar{x}} = \sum_j\mathbf{x}_j/n$?

The solution I am thinking of is to try combinations of the points, but that will take exponential time to try all combinations. I wonder if there is a faster way, utilising the knowledge of function $f$? I don't need an exact set of point that has the global maximum of $f$. Random algorithms that achieve reasonable result in faster time are much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this objective function matches your goal? If you just take as an example points of the form $(a,0)$, $(0,b)$ in the plane and $n=2$, it looks like its infimum is going to be $0$, for $a$ and $b$ very large.

Comment: @Kirill thank you for spotting this. There was a typo. It should be maximise $f$, not minimise $f$.

Comment: Are you setting $n$ as an input to the algorithm or do you let the algorithm find $n$ itself?

Comment: Additionally, something you could consider is using a randomized Interpolative Decomposition (ID) to figure out what data is the most important in your dataset, given you represent the data as a matrix $D \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times N}$. You would then just do a column ID and then you could (at worse case) do the brute force solution on a hopefully much smaller set of data points.